# how to istantiate and use std::less specialization object

Tags: c++, templates, functor

this is from a test.
the task: make a generic function object that behaves exactly like std::less with the exception that it always return true.
and the given solution:

```
template<class T>
struct myless : less<T> {
    bool operator(T, T) const { return true; }
};
```

How to instantiate and use it?

Comment: 50% of your code lines are correct.  They are `template<class T>` and `};`.

Comment: And how does it behave like `std::less` when it always returns true?

Answer (score 1):

Get another school.  The solution provided contains 2 lines that are correct.  They are `template<class T>` and `};`; everything else I would reject in code review.

```
template<class T>
struct myless {
  bool operator(T const&, T const&) const { return true; }
};
```

this is at least half correct.  For C++14 you also need

```
template<>
struct myless<void> {
  using is_transparent=void;
  template<class T, class U>
  bool operator(T const&, U const&) const { return true; }
};
```

Using it in std libraries is hard, as they all require axioms that your `myless` does not satisfy.

You create it via `my_less<int>()`.  You then pass that object two `int`s via *another* set of `()`s.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it in std::sort:

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator>
void sort (RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last);

template <class RandomAccessIterator, class Compare>
  void sort (RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, Compare comp);
```